# Blur behind popup on page load issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, onload

I am working on a site with a pop up, the only thing I am missing is a blur effect whenever this pop up is showing. This pop up will be showing every time the page loads, I therefore found a great blur code here on SO. Although that code is for a function where the blur effect is shown by a button. 
Because of that I have changed the code, so that instead of the button it is now `onLoad` which is launched from the body tag. 
The only issue is that the blur is showing up in front of the actual pop up which it isn't supposed to. I have tried to change the `z-index` in the CSS code for the pop up but it doesn't work.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uy4xvz12/16/) for my code (modified) Also apparently this doesn't work on Safari.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="overlay"> 
<div id="popup"> 
<a href="javascript:myBlurFunction(0);">X</a> 
</div>
</div>

<body id="main_container" onload="myBlurFunction(1)">

</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
myBlurFunction = function(state) {
    var containerElement = document.getElementById('main_container');
    var overlayEle = document.getElementById('overlay');

    if (state) {
        overlayEle.style.display = 'block';
        containerElement.setAttribute('class', 'blur');
    } else {
        overlayEle.style.display = 'none';
        containerElement.setAttribute('class', null);
    }
};
```

**CSS:**

```
.blur   {
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}

#overlay    {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    z-index: 999;
}

#popup {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    border: 5px solid rgb(90,90,90);
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edMa4/177/) for the stock code from the SO answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`body` tag should wrap all page content.
You might do as follows:

```
<body onload="myBlurFunction(1);">
  <div id="overlay"> 
   <div id="popup">
    <a href="javascript:myBlurFunction(0);">X</a> 
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="main_container"> 
      Whatever
  </div>
</body>
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxadfutp/)

Comment: Thank you very much, I have implemented it into my original code and it is working like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's because you are setting the blur in the Body.
The best aprouch, i guess, is create a Div to put the Blur, e show this div in 100% e after the popup with a Z-index higher than the Blur.

Answer (score 0):

applying blur to a tag has an impact on all inner tags, so try it this way.

do no set any styles on the body itself:

```
<body onload="myBlurFunction(true)">
```

do not include your popup inside the overlay (I added a button- you should use one instead of an anchor):

```
<div id="overlay" class="blur"></div>
<div id="popup">
  <button onclick="javascript: myBlurFunction(false);">X</button> 
  <a href="javascript: myBlurFunction(false);">LINK X</a> 
</div>
```

As you can see I added the blur css class to the overlay directly (uncommented code).

Modify your scripts:

```
myBlurFunction = function(state) {
    var overlayEle = document.getElementById('overlay');
    var popupEle = document.getElementById('popup');

    if (state) {
        overlayEle.style.display = 'block';
        //overlayEle.setAttribute('class', 'blur');
        popupEle.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        overlayEle.style.display = 'none';
        //overlayEle.setAttribute('class', null);
        popupEle.style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

set your popup position to fixed, because it's not in you overlay anymore:

```
#popup {
    position: fixed;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uy4xvz12/19/

Comment: update to fiddle to make it work in FF. https://jsfiddle.net/uy4xvz12/25/